# Create Login/Registration view from a main activity

Tags: android, android-intent, authentication, registration

Im starting to get crazy on my problem here.

I have a main activity that connects to a server on onCreate event, (the program must be connected to the server or else it shall not be working).

```
client_thread = new ServerCom(this);
```

Now I want to create a login view with (Username, Password and Login buttom with a user exist validation).
And when there is a login view there has to be some sort of registration view (with Username, Password, confim Password and a Registration button with a user exist validation).

I have create a Login and Registration Activity (for handeling some data with login and registration).

```
public ClassLogIn(MainActivity owner)
{
    this.owner = owner;
}
public ClassLogIn()
{

}
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == btnLogIn)
    {
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(userName.getText()) == false) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(userPassword.getText()) == false) {

                owner.LogIn(userName.getText(),userPassword.getText());
            }
        ...
```

To start the activitys from my mainActivity I have done this

```
else if(id == R.id.action_login){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ClassLogIn.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
else if(id == R.id.action_registera){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ClassRegistera.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
else if(id == R.id.action_Logout)
{
    client_thread.LogOut();
}
```

Now my problem is how can I get the userName value to my client_thread?
And also how can I call Owner.LogIn from my ClassLogIn activity?

```
public boolean LogIn(Editable UserName, Editable Password)
{
    return client_thread.LogIn(UserName.toString(),Password.toString());
}
```

Or do I trying to make something that is impossible in Android?

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head set up some IntentServies to catch intents and make then 
set up your variables.

And static variables are not an option ?

(Would add a comment but don't have enough reps)

Answer (score 0):

The specific code to do the following can differ depending on your specifics.

But in general, the procedure we do is the following:
NOTE - We use the WorkingStorage API to save parameters directly into the HHU (Hand Held Unit)

- When we initially launch we make an attempt to retrieve from within the HHU the login credentials which includes an Authorization ID.
- If they are present, we utilize the Authorization ID for subsequent WebService calls as needed throughout the Activities.
- If they are Not present, we launch a User Data Entry 'screen' and get Username & Password input.
- Then we send that data to the Server via a WebService call for validation.
- The WebService responds to the HHU with a Result.
- That Result is either a Valid Authorization ID or an Error Message (such as 'Not Valid', etc.).
- If it is a Valid Authorization ID, then all of the login credentials are saved to the HHU with the WorkingStorage API and are then available to be utilized for subsequent WebService calls.